# Deploying Python behind Nginx?

Tags: nginx, python

What is the best method deploying Python (including Django) behind Nginx?

Comment: Define "best"...

Comment: I would say "with the package manager of your distribution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) says that apache and mod_wsgi is the recommended way to get django into production.

We use nginx to proxy through to apache running mod_wsgi to serve our django site.  We have apache listening on `127.0.0.1` and use `proxy_pass` to pass requests to Apache.  The [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) has a bunch of examples.

I've also heard good things about [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). (and you would still use `proxy_pas`s in nginx)

Comment: Did you mean pass the requests to nginx instead of Apache?

Comment: No, nginx listens on our public IP and takes all requests.  It passes django requests to apache and handles the static file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use FastCGI for this on one of my sites (it's built on Django), both nginx and Django can do FastCGI natively. Addition: I have stress tested various approaches: nginx w/FastCGI, nginx w/Apache and then FastCGI, nginx w/Apache and then mod_wsgi and even nginx w/Apache and then mod_python. Performance was pretty much the same for a real application, so I chose nginx w/FastCGI without Apache to save RAM a bit.